# how to remove space between numbers in ASP.Net using RegEx

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to remove the space between the numbers using RegEx means I want to make a formated number from the input like `{lhs: \"1000 U.S. dollars\",rhs: \"58 740.6015 Indian rupees\",error: \"\",icc: true}` I tried the following expression `Regex regex = new Regex("rhs: \\\"(\\d+.\\d*)");` but its give me a error **"Input format not correct"**  so how can I remove the space between the numbers

P.S The currency name will change each time it called

Comment: As a general note, use verbatim strings to denote regular expressions. They make them much more readable: `@"rhs: \""(\d+.\d+*)"` (the double `"` is how you escape a double quote in verbatim strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following expression

```
string value = Regex.Replace(response.Split(',')[1], "[^.0-9]", "");
```